# Undefined method defaultStringLength()

Tags: php, laravel, neo4j

I want to use Vinelab/Neoeloquent package with laravel project. Earlier, I used MySql for storing my data. Now I want to use neo4j for that purpose.
I added `"vinelab/neoeloquent":"1.4.7"` in composer.json, in database.php

`'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION','neo4j')` , in connection array

```
'neo4j' => [
'driver' => 'neo4j',
'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '7474'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'neo4j'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'neo4j')
]
```

and in app.php `'Vinelab\NeoEloquent\NeoEloquentServiceProvider'`

After that, composer was updated successfully.
Furthermore,i changed .env from my previous conifguration for MySQL to one for neo4j

```
DB_CONNECTION=neo4j
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=7474
DB_DATABASE=neo4j
DB_USERNAME=neo4j
DB_PASSWORD=neo4j
```

After all that,i got some issues:
1.It wont recognize function label in migration file

```
public function up()
{
  Neo4jSchema::label('User', function(Blueprint $label) {
      $label->unique('email');
      $label->index('name');
  });
}
```

2.Even with that problem, when I try to migrate I got the following problem

```
In Facade.php line 223:

Call to undefined method Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Schema\Builder::defaultStringLength()
```

Keep in mind that after i changed .env file i couldnt update composer and got the same error

```
Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
@php artisan package:discover

In Facade.php line 223:

Call to undefined method Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Schema\Builder::defaultStringLength()

Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
Failed to update packages for ./composer.json.
```

Comment: which version of laravel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your **AppServiceProvider.php** with this,

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`
    `public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }`